# Purpose of void*

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

I was trying to understand casting in C. I tried [this code](https://ideone.com/HKQK8l) in IDEONE and got no errors at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i=1;
    char c = 'c';
    float f = 1.0;

    double* p = &i;
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)p);
    p = &c;
    printf("%c\n",*(char*)p);
    p = &f;
    printf("%f\n",*(float*)p);
    return 0;
}
```

But when compiled on C++ compiler [here](https://ideone.com/9BX2XI)  I got these errors:

```
prog.cpp:9:15: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'double*' in initialization
  double* p = &i;
               ^
prog.cpp:11:4: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'double*' in assignment
  p = &c;
    ^
prog.cpp:13:4: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'double*' in assignment
  p = &f;
    ^
```

and this is compatible with what I know so far; that is, I can't assign (in C++) incompatible types to any pointer, only to `void *`, like I did [here](https://ideone.com/pHsXcd):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i=1;
    char c = 'c';
    float f = 1.0;

    void* p = &i;
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)p);
    p = &c;
    printf("%c\n",*(char*)p);
    p = &f;
    printf("%f\n",*(float*)p);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if this code runs perfectly well in C, why do we need a `void` pointer? I can use any kind of pointer I want and then cast it when needed. I read that `void` pointer helps in making a code generic but that could be accomplished if we would treat `char *` as the default pointer, wouldn't it?

Comment: *if this code runs perfectly well in C*  Try it on hardware that has alignment restrictions and it won't run so well.  That's *one* reason why such restrictions exist.

Comment: What the .... are you trying to do? Types are important. They help prevent making mistakes. Use them. Avoid void pointers. Pointing to a spade is not the same as pointing to an apple.

Comment: Why do you wonder two differnt languages have different semantics? Same syntax or grammar does not imply same semantics.

Comment: Think for example to the malloc function, it returns void because has no idea of the type. Using a different kind of pointer would be misleading and would require an explicit cast.

Comment: Actually early versions of C used `char *` for such, e.g. `malloc` & friends. Now you use `void *` and shall not cast it to/from other pointer types (with one exception for variadic function arguments).

Comment: @Ed, I don't follow. I know int* is not the same as char* but if I cast it, why would it be better to cast from a void* instead of casting from an int*??

Comment: @Olaf, I understand the languages are different, no big surprise here. What I fail to see is why C, which is a weak type language, would require a void*
The fact that malloc used to return char* and the fact that malloc return value needs no casting just amplifies my question

Comment: @CIsForCookies: No it does not `void *` is the "universal pointer". I.e. you can assign to any other type without casting in C. This exactly because C is weakly typed. Before that, it was a `char *` (and there are still quite some relicts to allow using a `char *` for that - see _effective type_). With a distinct type, it now is possible to become a bit more type-safe - unless one insists on casting `void *`. Weakly typed language does not mean it should not provide any type-checking at all, or to add some more type-safety to the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compile you code with a serious ANSI C compiler, from C89 to C11, and you will get the same error:

```
Test.c(9): error #2168: Operands of '=' have incompatible types 'double *' and 'int *'.
Test.c(11): error #2168: Operands of '=' have incompatible types 'double *' and 'char *'.
Test.c(13): error #2168: Operands of '=' have incompatible types 'double *' and 'float *'.
```

I suppose that the online compiler is somewhat trimmed to accept any code also pre-ansi.
C is still a weak typed language, but such errors are not accepted by actual standard level.
C++ is more strong typed language (it needs it to work), so even the online compielr gives you the error.
The need of a **universal pointer**, `void *`, is absolutely required to act as a general pointer to be interchanged.