# What's the mistake in this code? unsigned int i; for (i = 100; i >=0; --i) printf("%d\n", i);

Tags: c

```
unsigned int i;

for (i = 100; i >=0; --i)
     printf("%d\n", i);
```

I ran this code on ideone and it prints until -10000

https://ideone.com/1TQ3Yu

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen? (it should actually endlessly print out numbers)

Comment: `unsigned int i;` --> `int i;`

Comment: @Amit I think ideone.com has a limit to prevent infinite output.

Comment: @Barmar - I assume that too. my comment is about what the code should do "in the real world".

Comment: Didn't your compiler give you any warnings? It should have flagged up the useless comparison in your `for()` loop, and your use of a signed format specifier (`%d`) to print an unsigned variable. Get into the habit of always compiling your code with warnings switched on (by using the `-Wall` command line flag). And learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: A **real** compiler would have warned against signed/unsigned comparison. Ideone seems to work on a pre-ansi compiler.

Comment: @Frankie_C Ideone uses GCC 5.1, according to the language selection box. Maybe they just suppress the warnings.

Comment: @szczurcio Maybe they suppressed **a lot of warnings** :-D. It suppressed other warnings here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830416/purpose-of-void/34831267#34831267

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` is unsigned, it will always be `>=0`

Using the format string `%d` interprets it as a signed integer when printing. To view it unsigned, use `%u`.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned i` will always be `>=0`, so `int` should be used instead of `unsigned int` in this case.

The problem is that `i` becomes (or wants to become) negative, but since it's an `unsigned int`, it stays positive and loops forever (-1 = 0xffffffff in 32-bit).

Comment: And what if the purpose is to print 0 as well?

Comment: @Amit - You're right :) Updated.

Comment: But it still won't print 0. You just exclaimed that it won't but that's not the same as "fixing" your logic (which is impractical without signed-ness)

Comment: @Amit - Ok, I removed the second option.